# TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len(), LogisticRegression()

Tags: classification, logistic-regression

I'm trying to fit my Logistic Regression model, but I'm running into an error that I don't understand. Looked around and haven't found a straight answer.

Shape of independent features (X): (495,30)

Shape of dependent feature (y): (495,)

The dependent feature holds binary values (0,1) and the values are currently of type "int". This is probably where the problem is occurring, but I don't understand what I need to do to fix the issue.

This is the error I'm getting when I try fitting to sklearn LogisticRegression():

```
c_param = [1,10,100,1000]

rand_grid = {'kbest__k':list(range(5,10)),
            'log__C':c_param,
            'log__random_state':42}

log_rand = RandomizedSearchCV(pipe_opt('log',LogisticRegression()),rand_grid,n_iter=100,cv=3,
                              random_state=42,n_jobs=-1)
log_rand.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

[image]

Comment: What about if log_random_state = [42]?

Comment: Wow that worked! Why did I need to put [ ] around the random_state?

Comment: because RandomizedSearchCV demands list of values to seach on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RandomizedSearchCV` expects you provide dictionary of parameters-values to try, like in your code above:

```
rand_grid = {'log__C':[1,10,100,1000],
             'log__random_state':42} # values should be in []
```

Since the idea is to search values which give the best performance, you are expected to provide several values, as a **list of values**. Though in your case you only provided only one value, it won't raise error as long as it was written as list (inside `[]`).

However it's a bit weird if you only have one value to search. So better you fix those values when you initialize the estimator (i.e LogisticRegression())., e.g:

```
# you want to see which values perform best for params C and max_iter.
rand_grid = {'log__C':[1,10,100,1000]
             'log__max_iter': [100,200,300]}  

# you have fix value for params random_state, penalty and fit_intercept
logReg = LogisticRegression(random_state=42, penalty='l1', fit_intercept=False)

log_rand = RandomizedSearchCV(pipe_opt('log',logReg),
                              rand_grid,n_iter=100,cv=3,
                              random_state=42,n_jobs=-1)
```